# Is there any way to transverse lava pools?

Tags: age-of-wonders-4

In Age of Wonders 3, you could cross lava pools with units that had Flying, Floating, or Lava Walking abilities. In Age of Wonders 4 however, there don't appear to be an units with Lava Walking, nor can Flying or Floating units cross lava pools.

Do any units exist that can cross over lava, or is it similarly impassable as bedrock?